# retrieve the value of a timestamp field with adodb - how to read a byte array from classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, binary, timestamp, ado, arrays

I'm working with asp and adodb, querying a database (ms sql 2005)

I have a field named stamp, of type timestamp

in asp I get the following

field.ActualSize: 8
field.DefinedSize: 
field.Name: Stamp
field.Type: adBinary (128)

field.Attributes: 528 (adFldFixed (16) + adFldRowVersion (512) )
  (so adFldLong is NOT turned on, so I can't use getchunk method!)
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676678(VS.85).aspx

At the debugger, if I type field.value I get the following

```
? field.value
{...}
    (0): 0
    (1): 0
    (2): 0
    (3): 0
    (4): 0
    (5): 35
    (6): 163
    (7): 124
```

That is what I want to GET!!!! but I don't know how to do it...

I can assign it to a variable, but I can't get each element

I tried with

```
? cstr( field.value )
""
```

```
? field.value(0)
Número de argumentos erróneo o asignación de propiedad no válida: 'field.value'
```

(wrong number of arguments)

```
? vartype( field.value )
8209 ( 8192-vbArray + 17-vbByte )
```

So, the problem is I have an array of bytes, well, how do I read it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I've found it...

http://www.ureader.com/msg/16755039.aspx

I had to use

h = hex( ascb( midb( barray, c, 1 ) ) )

to convert it to hex...

so I made something like this

```
    s = ""

    for c = lbound( barray ) + 1 to ubound( barray ) + 1
        h = hex( ascb( midb( barray, c, 1 ) ) )
        h = padl( h, 2, "0" )
        s = s & h & " "
    next
```